# Second last Tuesday for every month

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

How to get the date of second last Tuesday for month?

```
import calendar
todayyear= date.datetime.today().year
todayday = date.datetime.today().day
c = calendar.TextCalendar(calendar.SUNDAY)
str = c.formatmonth(todayyear,todayday)
print(str)

    October 2020
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
             1  2  3
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

I need to print out the date of second last Tuesday of this month which is 20th in this particular case but it should work for any month. Please advise how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[relative delta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) to the rescue!

You'll want to do something like:

1. Get the last DATE of the month
2. Convert that DATE to a DAY using relative detla
3. Work the DAY backward to a Tuesday by DATE (That's the last Tuesday of the month)
4. Subtract one week from that DATE

As you can tell, be careful of DATE and DAY

Comment: I used : `now+relativedelta(day=31, weekday=TU(-2))`  from relative delta. I am just trying to figure out why do i even need to specify day = 31?

Comment: Relative delta is "relative" to anything with time. 31 days is the longest any month can be, so "relatively" its the last day of every month. Does that make sense?

Comment: I guess but then why have you specify 31 since it cannot go any longer anyway? I am just thinking if there is going to be any reason anyone would need to use 28.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can get all the days from [`Calendar.itermonthdays4()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.Calendar.itermonthdays4) and filter them by the day and month. Then just index the second to last with `[-2]`

```
import calendar

c = calendar.Calendar()
year = 2020
day = 1

for month in range(1, 13):
    secondLastTues = list(filter(lambda d:d[3] == day and d[1] == month, 
                                 c.itermonthdays4(year, month)))[-2]
    print(secondLastTues)
```

Result:

```
(2020, 1, 21, 1)
(2020, 2, 18, 1)
(2020, 3, 24, 1)
(2020, 4, 21, 1)
(2020, 5, 19, 1)
(2020, 6, 23, 1)
(2020, 7, 21, 1)
(2020, 8, 18, 1)
(2020, 9, 22, 1)
(2020, 10, 20, 1)
(2020, 11, 17, 1)
(2020, 12, 22, 1)
```

Comment: Any special reason for using lambda vs. a comprehension like - `[d for d in list(c.itermonthdays4(year, month)) if d[3] == day][-2]`?

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere I think the comprehension is good too. But I think you need to check the month (`d[1] == month`) because `calendar ` doesn't just give dates within the given month.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
weeks=str.split('\n')
if len(weeks[-1].split())<3: print(weeks[-3][2])
else: print(weeks[-2][2])
```

This will print second last Tuesday. Hope this is helpful. You can comment if it is not clear.

Comment: Please tell if it is working. I am new and it would help my self-esteem.